# finding the first index of a number in an array through recursion

Tags: java, recursion

So in this problem i am trying to find the index of a given number in an array through recursion,it gives wrong output. Any assistance would be appreciated.
Here is my code:

```
public class first_index {
// i refers to index, x is element
    public static int firstIndex(int input[], int x,int i){

        if(i >= input.length - 1){
            if(input[i]==x)
                return i;
            else
                return -1;
        }
        int b;
        b=firstIndex(input,x,i+1);
        if(b!=-1){
            if(input[i]==x)
                return i+1;
            else
                return i-1;
        }
        else{
            if(input[i]==x)
                return i;
            else
                return -1;
        }
        }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int input[] = {1,2,3,5,9,0};
        System.out.println(firstIndex(input,9,0));

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If the current index contains the number you are looking for, you should return that index.

Only if it doesn't, you should make a recursive call to search for the number in the rest of the array.

```
public static int firstIndex(int input[], int x,int i) {
    if (i > input.length - 1) { // i is beyond the indices of the array, 
                                // so the number is not found
        return -1;
    }

    if(input[i]==x) { // current index is the first index that contains x
        return i;
    } else { // make a recursive call to find the first index of x in the rest of the array
        return firstIndex(input,x,i+1);
    }
}
```

which can also be written as:

```
public static int firstIndex(int input[], int x,int i) {
    if(i > input.length - 1) {
        return -1;
    }

    return (input[i] == x) ? i : firstIndex(input, x, i+1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
public static int firstIndex(int input[], int x,int i){
    if(i >= input.length) {
        return -1;
    } else if(input[i]==x)
        return i;
    } else {
        return firstIndex(input,x,i+1);
    }
}
```